# One flag vs multiple flags

Tags: support, flags

Although infrequent, I have noticed that some users comment on some questions to inform other users that they should flag the question for some reason or another. Typically, it is my opinion that the reported flag is appropriate, though not always.

It occurs to me that flagging only really alerts a moderator or pushes the question to a potential review queue. As such, would it make an actual difference if another user came along and flagged the question as per the original comments? Assuming the user making the original comments already flagged the question as they report, I am wondering if there would be any advantage to flagging the question *again*.

Is there any difference between one user flagging a post and multiple users flagging the post *under the same flag reason*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no *harm* in this. We won't see 4 different instances of the same question. We see one with the appropriate flags below it.

As for whether it matters - depends on the flags. For spam and abusive flags, piling on the flags takes care of the problem *automatically*.

We do see *who flagged* and *how many* flags there are in the review queue though flags for the same question are usually consolidated. *If* we have a *massive* number of flags, it's a useful tool for triage. On a busy day, with my moderation strategy, questions with more flags get *looked at first*. Your local moderation style may vary.

*If* it's someone telling a new user to flag to migrate, and it's a valid migration target, voting to close-migrate would be an option too.